# Merging Two Dataframes by date range

Tags: r, date

Two Dataframes: A - Companies with their Listing Date, B - Daily Trading Data  After One Year.

Problem - Merging Data by incrementing listing date by one year creates NA values as some dates fall on weekends or holidays. Need to find dates near the one-year mark.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can find weekdays with wday function in lubridate and later subset the data only based on weekdays , here is a short example 
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- data_frame(date = seq(ymd("2018-06-01"), ymd("2018-09-30"), by = "days"))

days <- mutate(df, day = wday(date, label = T)) %>%
  filter(day != "Sat", day != "Sun") %>%
  nrow()

Comment: Possibly this answer applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934361/merge-2-dataframes-if-value-within-range