# Non-equi join in tidyverse

Tags: r, join, dplyr, dbplyr, dtplyr

I was wondering whether someone knows if the `dplyr` extension packages (`dbplyr` and `dtplyr`) allow non-equi joins within the usual dplyr workflow? I rarely need `data.table`, but fast non-equi joins are the only moments where I always need to `setDT`, then perform the join and then switch back with `as_tibble()`. I scrolled through the issues in the packages on github but didn't find whether this is something that's planned or already implemented.

Comment: Interesting, but not yet pushed forward : https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr/issues/133

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins/

Comment: You might consider the `fuzzyjoin` package.

Comment: Inner join on means cross join where. Cross join means inner join on true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Non-equi joins are available since `1.1.0` via the function [`join_by`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join_by.html?q=join_by#ref-usage). To create non-equi joins, you can use `<`, `>`, `>=`, `<=`, or helpers `between`, `within`, `overlaps` and `nearest`.

```r
library(dplyr)

#Example from https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/5910.

set.seed(123)
dates <- as.Date("2019-01-01") + 0:4
needles <- tibble(dates = dates, x = sample(length(dates)))

set.seed(123)
lower <- as.Date("2019-01-01") + sample(6, 5, replace = TRUE)
upper <- lower + sample(2, 5, replace = TRUE)
haystack <- tibble(lower = lower, upper = upper, y = sample(length(lower)))

needles
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   dates          x
#>   <date>     <int>
#> 1 2019-01-01     3
#> 2 2019-01-02     2
#> 3 2019-01-03     5
#> 4 2019-01-04     4
#> 5 2019-01-05     1
haystack
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   lower      upper          y
#>   <date>     <date>     <int>
#> 1 2019-01-04 2019-01-06     1
#> 2 2019-01-07 2019-01-08     2
#> 3 2019-01-04 2019-01-05     3
#> 4 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     4
#> 5 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     5

# Non-equi join
# For each row in `needles`, find locations in `haystack` matching the condition
left_join(needles, haystack, by = join_by(dates >= lower, dates <= upper))
#> # A tibble: 12 x 5
#>    dates          x lower      upper          y
#>    <date>     <int> <date>     <date>     <int>
#>  1 2019-01-01     3 NA         NA            NA
#>  2 2019-01-02     2 NA         NA            NA
#>  3 2019-01-03     5 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     4
#>  4 2019-01-03     5 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     5
#>  5 2019-01-04     4 2019-01-04 2019-01-06     1
#>  6 2019-01-04     4 2019-01-04 2019-01-05     3
#>  7 2019-01-04     4 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     4
#>  8 2019-01-04     4 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     5
#>  9 2019-01-05     1 2019-01-04 2019-01-06     1
#> 10 2019-01-05     1 2019-01-04 2019-01-05     3
#> 11 2019-01-05     1 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     4
#> 12 2019-01-05     1 2019-01-03 2019-01-05     5
```

Answer (score 5):

There has been a new option for this in `dbplyr` since the version 1.4.0: `sql_on`. Citing [Kirill Müller](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4214#issuecomment-466256033):

> There is #2240 for dplyr, but it's going to take a while. For databases we already have a workaround [ie. generic SQL joins].

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
tbl1 <- memdb_frame(a = 1:3, b = 4:2)
tbl2 <- memdb_frame(c = 1:3, b = 2:0)
left_join(tbl1, tbl2, sql_on = "LHS.b < RHS.c")
```

Answer (score 2):

For **dbplyr**: While SQL supports non-equi joins, I have not found a dplyr approach that is equivalent. My usual work around is very similar to the r-bloggers link posted by @Waldi to join on the equality conditions and then filter on the inequality conditions.

For example:

```r
output = join(df1, df2, by = c("df1_id" = "df2_id")) %>%
  filter(df1_date <= df2_date)
```

This translates to SQL similar to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM df1
JOIN df2
ON df1_id = df2_id
WHERE df1_date <= df2_date
```

Which is not that different from:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM df1
JOIN df2
ON df1_id = df2_id
AND df1_date <= df2_date
```

Comment: "Which is not that different from:" Thanks for the answer. Are there cases when the two differ?

Comment: There may be some cases when using a left, right, or outer join that the two return different output. Suppose we used a left join and there was a record where `df1_date` was `NULL` - in an inequality join this record would be part of the output with nothing joined to it, but using the WHERE clause this record might be dropped. However, in these kinds of cases you probably want to handle `NULL` values explicitly.