# How do find a maximum value that matches multiple criteria in r?

Tags: r

I have two databases, one with daily metrics `df` and one with benchmarked metrics (with a date attached) `benchmark_df`. I would like to find the percentage of the daily metrics compared to the max of the benchmark metrics - but only for benchmark dates that are less than or equal to the previous dates.

So a straight forward answer would be using `left_join()` and `mutate(perc_benchmark = metric_a / benchmark_metric_a)` where `benchmark_metric_a` is the the max value less than or equal to the `metric_a` date... but I'm not sure if I can do this with a `left_join()` or if there is a workaround.

So in the example data frames below. Player B would have a `perc_benchmark` of `50%` (0.5/1) from 8-1 to 8-6, 8-7 would be `25%` (0.5/2), and then 8-8 would be `75%` (1.5/2), etc.

```
df <- tibble(player =  rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 21),
             date = as.Date(rep(seq(as.Date('2022-08-01'), by = 'day', length.out= 21), each = 2)),
             # metric_a values are only patterned for testing purposes, they would not be in the actual dataframe
             metric_a = c(rep(0.5, times = 14),rep(c(0.5, 1.5), times = 7),rep(c(0.5, 3), times = 7)))

benchmark_df <- tibble(player = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 3),
                       date = as.Date(rep(c('2022-08-01', '2022-08-07', '2022-08-16'), each = 2)),
                       benchmark_metric_a = c(1,1,0.5,2,1,3))
```

Comment: You can do [non-equi joins](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins/#non-equi-joins-with-sqldf) in R, with [**`sqldf`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sqldf) or [**`data.table`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table).  Also, you you mind providing a **sample of your desired output**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) package is developing [support for non-equi `*_join()`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73488075).

> ...using **`left_join()`**...where `benchmark_metric_a` is the the max value **less than or equal to** the `metric_a date`...

In the meantime, here's a solution that uses a [non-equi join](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/02/the-unequalled-joy-of-non-equi-joins#non-equi-joins-with-data.table) with the [**`data.table`**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=data.table) package, whose performance is [superior at scale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718317).

## Solution

First prepare your datasets as [`data.table`](https://rdrr.io/github/Rdatatable/data.table/man/data.table.html)s.

```r
library(data.table)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df' and 'benchmark_df'.
# ...


# Convert datasets into 'data.table's.
setDT(df)
setDT(benchmark_df)
```

Then apply the following **`data.table`** "chain", which is analogous to the **`dplyr`** workflow:

```r
# Perform a LEFT JOIN of 'df' to 'benchmark_df'...
result <- benchmark_df[df, .(  
    # ...using a subset of columns...
    player,
    bench_date = x.date,
    benchmark_metric_a,
    metric_date = i.date,
    metric_a
  ),
  # ...where players match and benchmark dates are earlier (or concurrent). 
  on = .(player, date <= date)
  
# Calculate the max benchmark...
][, .(
    benchmark_metric_a = max(benchmark_metric_a),
    # ...while preserving the metric...
    metric_a = first(metric_a)
  ),
  # ...for each player as of each date.
  by = .(player, metric_date)
  
# Calculate the percentage.
][, `:=`(
  perc_benchmark = metric_a / benchmark_metric_a
  
# Select the desired columns.
)][, .(
  player,
  date = metric_date,
  metric_a,
  perc_benchmark
  
# Restore original ordering from 'df': sort by 'date' and then 'player'.
)][order(
  date,
  player
)]
```

## Result

Given a `df` and `benchmark_df` like your examples

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  player =  rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 21),
  date = as.Date(rep(seq(as.Date('2022-08-01'), by = 'day', length.out= 21), each = 2)),
  # metric_a values are only patterned for testing purposes, they would not be in the actual dataframe
  metric_a = c(rep(0.5, times = 14),rep(c(0.5, 1.5), times = 7),rep(c(0.5, 3), times = 7))
)

benchmark_df <- tibble(
  player = rep(LETTERS[1:2], times = 3),
  date = as.Date(rep(c('2022-08-01', '2022-08-07', '2022-08-16'), each = 2)),
  benchmark_metric_a = c(1,1,0.5,2,1,3)
)
```

this chain should yield the following `data.table` for `result`, where the `df` data is now augmented with the `perc_benchmark` column:

```r
    player       date metric_a perc_benchmark
 1:      A 2022-08-01      0.5           0.50
 2:      B 2022-08-01      0.5           0.50
 3:      A 2022-08-02      0.5           0.50
 4:      B 2022-08-02      0.5           0.50
 5:      A 2022-08-03      0.5           0.50
 6:      B 2022-08-03      0.5           0.50
 7:      A 2022-08-04      0.5           0.50
 8:      B 2022-08-04      0.5           0.50
 9:      A 2022-08-05      0.5           0.50
10:      B 2022-08-05      0.5           0.50
11:      A 2022-08-06      0.5           0.50
12:      B 2022-08-06      0.5           0.50
13:      A 2022-08-07      0.5           0.50
14:      B 2022-08-07      0.5           0.25
15:      A 2022-08-08      0.5           0.50
16:      B 2022-08-08      1.5           0.75
17:      A 2022-08-09      0.5           0.50
18:      B 2022-08-09      1.5           0.75
19:      A 2022-08-10      0.5           0.50
20:      B 2022-08-10      1.5           0.75
21:      A 2022-08-11      0.5           0.50
22:      B 2022-08-11      1.5           0.75
23:      A 2022-08-12      0.5           0.50
24:      B 2022-08-12      1.5           0.75
25:      A 2022-08-13      0.5           0.50
26:      B 2022-08-13      1.5           0.75
27:      A 2022-08-14      0.5           0.50
28:      B 2022-08-14      1.5           0.75
29:      A 2022-08-15      0.5           0.50
30:      B 2022-08-15      3.0           1.50
31:      A 2022-08-16      0.5           0.50
32:      B 2022-08-16      3.0           1.00
33:      A 2022-08-17      0.5           0.50
34:      B 2022-08-17      3.0           1.00
35:      A 2022-08-18      0.5           0.50
36:      B 2022-08-18      3.0           1.00
37:      A 2022-08-19      0.5           0.50
38:      B 2022-08-19      3.0           1.00
39:      A 2022-08-20      0.5           0.50
40:      B 2022-08-20      3.0           1.00
41:      A 2022-08-21      0.5           0.50
42:      B 2022-08-21      3.0           1.00
    player       date metric_a perc_benchmark
```

## Note

If you want to convert this back into `tibble` form, then simply use [`as_tibble()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/reexports.html#:%7E:text=as_tibble) on the `result`.

Comment: Working my way through your solution and it looks like the max call is grabbing the max from both players where as I want to grab the max per player. Probably wasn't clear in my question. This is my first time using data.table to this extent so I'm not sure how to add that into your existing code.

Comment: I looked at your edits and it appears you had it initially with the `on = .(player, date >=date)`

Comment: @seansteele That's probably the way to go: `on = .(player, date >=date)`.

Comment: @seansteele I have edited the solution accordingly.  If the revised solution achieves your desired result, kindly upvote.  :)