# Dplyr non-equi join no longer accepting join_by argument

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

This code worked a couple days ago:

```
df<- tribble(
  ~ unique_id, ~event_type, ~ event_date,
  'id_101', 'A_type_event', '2022-01-01',
  'id_101', 'B_type_event', '2022-02-01',
  'id_101', 'A_type_event', '2022-02-15',
  'id_101', 'A_type_event', '2022-02-28',
  'id_101', 'B_type_event', '2022-03-01',
  'id_101', 'C_type_event', '2022-03-10',
  'id_101', 'A_type_event', '2022-03-20',
  'id_101', 'C_type_event', '2022-04-01'
)
```

```
 left_join(
  df %>% filter(event_type == "A_type_event"),  # match A_type_event
  df %>% filter(event_type == "C_type_event"),   # with C_type_event
  #join_by(event_date < event_date),          # where A_type_event before C_type_event
  join_by(unique_id, event_date < event_date), # ... and unique id matches
  multiple = "first")                        # and just keep first match
```

> Error code now is:  Error in dplyr::common_by(): ! by must be a
> (named) character vector, list, or NULL for natural   joins (not
> recommended in production code), not a <dplyr_join_by> object.

I tested the sample code on [rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/github/tidyverse/dplyr/man/join_by.html) and another related [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372705/non-equi-join-in-tidyverse) on the same topic and they both return the same error.

Any idea how to fix the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear about the version used in the question.  `join_by` is in devel version of `dplyr`.  The code works if we install the devel version as

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

---

```
library(dplyr)
> left_join(
+   df %>% filter(event_type == "A_type_event"),  # match A_type_event
+   df %>% filter(event_type == "C_type_event"),   # with C_type_event
+   #join_by(event_date < event_date),          # where A_type_event before C_type_event
+   join_by(unique_id, event_date < event_date), # ... and unique id matches
+   multiple = "first")                       
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  unique_id event_type.x event_date.x event_type.y event_date.y
  <chr>     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
1 id_101    A_type_event 2022-01-01   C_type_event 2022-03-10  
2 id_101    A_type_event 2022-02-15   C_type_event 2022-03-10  
3 id_101    A_type_event 2022-02-28   C_type_event 2022-03-10  
4 id_101    A_type_event 2022-03-20   C_type_event 2022-04-01
```

Comment: It worked after I updated dplyr with github. Thanks