# Merge 2 dataframes if range includes value

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

A [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934361/merge-2-dataframes-if-value-within-range) with the inverse problem has been asked before, but the same function does not apply.

Consider these two databases.

```
df1<- data.frame(TypeA=paste0("A",1:3), Position=c(1, 5, 9))
df2<- data.frame(TypeB=paste0("B",1:5),StartPosition=c(0, 3, 7, 8,  20), EndPosition=c(2, 4, 8, 18, 25))
```

How can I obtain the rows in df2 whose range (between StartPosition and EndPosition) includes the value (Position) in df1?

One would expect:

```
TypeB   StartPosition EndPosition  TypeA
B1      0             2            A1
B4      8             18           A3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [join_by()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76937962/4145280):

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df1, df2, join_by(between(Position, StartPosition, EndPosition)))
```

Comment: I get an error saying function does not exits... it looks like join_by is only available in the devel version... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141591/dplyr-non-equi-join-no-longer-accepting-join-by-argument

Comment: No, that was from a year ago. Try running install.packages("dplyr") to update your dplyr!

Comment: This join_by is a very nice/useful hidden gem/function..came to learn...thank you @Mark

Comment: @Camilo check out my answer from a while back I linked to! It has more details on it there

Answer (score 1):

I found a likely solution using  the package sqldf:

```
Result= sqldf("select df1.*, df2.* from df1, df2 
  WHERE df1.Position between df2.StartPosition AND df2.EndPosition")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform the operation rowise, you can do this:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(n = 1:n())
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(n = 1:n())

df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "n") %>% 
  filter(between(Position, StartPosition, EndPosition))
```

Comment: but this assumes that the two databases also need to have in common the column you just created (n), can this work considering only the positions.